# Unity for each JSONnode in JSONObject

Tags: c#, json, node.js, unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity and Socket.IO and a NodeJS server when a player joins i need to send him the info abbout the other players to add them to his game. The server sends this json string:

```
{  
   "players":{  
      "/#3vd98L1t96vgMwRsAAAB":{  
         "name":"Player #2",
         "x":0,
         "y":0
      },
      "/#RaLyZw7Rnp94nDXkAAAF":{  
         "name":"Player #6",
         "x":0,
         "y":0
      }
   }
}
```

But i can't find out how to forloop this in unity?
I thought making a object out of it would work so this is what i came up with:

```
JSONObject players = new JSONObject(e.data.GetField("players").ToString());
```

But how can i make a foreach loop out of it?

Comment: I am not getting the question here, can you give the sample output

Comment: @Devank i need a for each loop to insert all players so a for each loop that loops through: "/#3vd98L1t96vgMwRsAAAB" and through: "/#RaLyZw7Rnp94nDXkAAAF"

The sample output is just the string as the example above: {"players":{"/#z91LtpNg70y3GiUDAAAA":{"name":"Player #1","x":0,"y":0}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `e.data` is a [`JSONObject`](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject) created from the JSON you show, you can do:

```
var players = e.data.GetField("players");

for(int i = 0; i < players.list.Count; i++)
{
    string playerKey = (string)players.keys[i];
    JSONObject playerData = (JSONObject)players.list[i];
    // Process the player key and data as you need.
}
```

For the relevant docs see [JSONObject: Decoding](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject#Decoding).

For convenience, you might want to encapsulate this logic in an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for later re-use:

```
public static class JSONObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JSONObject>> NameValuePairs(this JSONObject obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (obj.type != JSONObject.Type.OBJECT)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Incoming object type {0} is not JSONObject.Type.OBJECT.", obj.type));
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.list.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = (string)obj.keys[i];
            JSONObject j = (JSONObject)obj.list[i];
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, JSONObject>(key, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
foreach (var pair in players.NameValuePairs())
{
    // Process the player key and data as you need.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast and easy solution! it fits perfect and it does the job! thank you so much!

Comment: @MennovanHout - added an extension method for convenience.

Comment: Thank you you made such a great explanation @dbc

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the library you are using. Unity added native `Jason` serialzer in version **5.3**.

Convert Class to `Json` string:

```
string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(className);
```

Convert Json string to class:

```
ClassName serializedPlayer = new ClassName();
serializedPlayer = JsonUtility.FromJson<ClassName>(jsonString);
```

The answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314) describes how to use **array** json. It's a long process to be reposted but it is what you are looking for. You should read the second solution that says "**2. MULTIPLE DATA(ARRAY JSON)**."